# When I use 'rm -rf .git ' then 'git init', the source files are disappear?

Tags: git, init, rm

Here are the operations on mac:(the 9977 ,I found the source files are disappear) :

```
 9923  git log
 9924  git remote
 9925  git remote -v
  9926  git remote set-url --add  origin ssh://xxx.git
  9927  git remote -v
  9928  git remote --delete origin https://github.com/ant-design/ant-     design-pro.git
  9929  git remote set-url --delete origin https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro.git
  9930  git remote -v
  9931  git branch
  9932  git checkout -b 20181xxxx
  9933  git remote
  9934  git st
  9935  git add .
  9936  git commit -m 'login'
  9937  git remote -v
  9938  git branch
  9939  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/20181xxxx
  9940  git branch -a
  9941  git pull
  9942  git branch -a
  9943  git checkout master
  9944  git pull
  9945  git branch -a
  9946  git fetch
  9947  git checkout 20181xxxx
  9948  git status -s
  9949  ll
  9950  git pull
  9951  gitk
  9952  ll
  9953  ll -la
  9954  rm -rf .git
  9955  git init
  9956  git remote add origin ssh://xxx.git
  9957  git remote -v
  9958  git status -s
  9959  git pull
  9960  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/20181xxxx
  9961  git status -s
  9962  ll
  9963  git remote -v
  9964  git branch -a
  9965  git pull
  9966  git checkout 20181xxxx
  9967  git status -s
  9968  git stash
  9969  git add .
  9970  git status -s
  9971  git checkout 20181xxxx
  9972  git commit -m "init"
  9973  git checkout 20181xxxx
  9974  git status -s
  9975  ll
  9976  rm -rf .git
  9977  git init
  9978  git remote add origin ssh://xxx.git
  9979  git status -s
  9980  cd src
  9981  ll
  9982  cd pages/
```

Comment: Looks like the downvoter forget about telling you to publish only the necessary code and tell what have you tried so far to fix the problem yourself (In this case, understand what happened).

Comment: If someone is a new contributor (like you posting this question) then the people should give you an opportunity to correct your mistakes in your questions before downvoting. At least check the time that has passed from the first comment telling how to make this question better and, if it is more than an hour and the post keeps its mistakes only then a downvote should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `rm -rf .git` and then `git init` does not make anything dissapear. It just re-create the repository, so there is nothing wrong with those commands.

Secondly, you used a command named git st, which is not a valid git command. If you have set an alias for that command it would be nice to know in order to give a better answer.

I don't know the output of your commands, but I can tell you that this might be because:

1. When you made git pull you pulled some changes that deleted some files.
2. You checked out a branch that does not contain your source files.
3. You made a stash and forgot to apply it to restore its contents.

Comment: `git st` is most plausibly an alias for `git status`, but we need to see how it's actually defined.